# 4x4 matrix last element significance?

Tags: graphics, matrix, 3d, direct3d

Im looking to piggyback a float value on a 4x4 matrix im transfering. The matrix in question is used for various xyz vector transforms. As far as i understand the first 3x3 of the matrix facilitates the rotation and scale transforms with the 4th value of the first 3 rows offset the pivot of the transform and the first 3 elements of the bottom row do the positional offset but what does the last element do? As far as i've seen it is always 1 and does absolutely nothing, is there any harm in me making a good use of it?

Comment: what facility/tool/API/etc. are you using this for?  This is not a math/matrix standard, its a convention of whatever you are passing this matrix too.

Comment: Though my offhand guess would be that it controls scaling.

Comment: the matrices get created using d3dx functions and applied in hlsl environment, scaling was also my first thought but i tried 100 random matrices on random vectors and changing the last value did absolutely nothing

Comment: Ahh, ***Direct3D***.  I'll add the tag so someone who knows this can reply.

Comment: well, even though it makes no difference in multiplying a matrix with a vector3 it sure does make a difference in multiplying matrix*matrix (read colossal disaster) so i guess it is useful for something and i'll just leave it alone.

Answer (score 8):

If (as your question suggests) the convention is that points are column vectors, and the last elements of the first 3 rows determine the translation, then the first 3 elements of the bottom row are *not* a positional offset:  the 4th row of a transformation matrix is used for perspective projection, which is how the camera maps 3D points onto the 2D viewport.  A sketch of how the 4x4 matrix is used to map points:

```
result   =       4x4 matrix      *  point

[ x' ]       [ Rxx Rxy Rxz Tx ]     [ x ]
[    ]       [                ]     [   ]     ->    R** is the rotation/scaling matrix
[ y' ]       [ Ryx Ryy Ryz Ty ]     [ y ]
[    ]   =   [                ]  *  [   ]           T* is the translation vector
[ z' ]       [ Rzx Rzy Rzz Tz ]     [ z ]
[    ]       [                ]     [   ]           P* fixes the camera projection plane
[ w' ]       [ Px  Py  Pz  Pw ]     [ w ]

-> x' = dot_product3([Rxx,Rxy,Rxz], [x,y,z])  + Tx * w
-> y' = dot_product3([Ryx,Ryy,Ryz], [x,y,z])  + Ty * w
-> z' = dot_product3([Rzx,Rzy,Rzz], [x,y,z])  + Tz * w
-> w' = dot_product4([Px,Py,Pz,Pw], [x,y,z,w])
```

The final step in the 3D point -> 2D screen mapping is to divide by the 4th (`w'`) coordinate -- so, for standard geometric transformations, the last row should generally be `[0,0,0,1]`, which leaves the `w` coordinate unchanged.

If the first 3 elements of the bottom row are not `0`, the matrix will typically generate a weird, nonuniform distortion of the 3D space.  And, although it is possible to use the last element as a uniform inverse scaling factor, it is probably better to do your scaling with the upper left 3x3 submatrix, and leave the bottom row exclusively for the camera.